# How to replace NA values in one dataframe from another dependent on matching several columns

Tags: r, dplyr

df1

| Name | Surname | DOB | Visit date | ID Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Smith | 02/03/2014 | 02/12/2023 | 123 |
| Adam | Smith | 02/03/2014 | 01/11/2020 | NA |
| Ben | Walker | 14/10/1944 | 04/05/2019 | 523 |
| Carmen | Smith | 22/11/1975 | 25/12/2000 | NA |

df2

| Name | Surname | DOB | ID Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Smith | 02/03/2014 | 123 |
| Ben | Walker | 14/10/1944 | 523 |
| Carmen | Smith | 22/11/1975 | 422 |
| Daniel | Fernando | 07/12/1983 | 989 |

Hello,
Could you please tell me how to fill in the missing ID numbers in df1 from those in df2, but only if the name and surname and DOB all match? This is a subset, my actual dataset has ~ 5000 entries.

I have tried using left_join, but I then end up with more rows than I started with because it appears to duplicate entries. I'm very new to R, so all help much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rows_patch` in dplyr package. `unmatched="ignore"` would ignore rows in df2 not in df1.

```
library(dplyr)
rows_patch(df1,df2,by=c('Name','Surname','DOB'),unmatched="ignore")

    Name Surname        DOB Visit_date ID_Number
1   Adam   Smith 02/03/2014 02/12/2023       123
2   Adam   Smith 02/03/2014 01/11/2020       123
3    Ben  Walker 14/10/1944 04/05/2019       523
4 Carmen   Smith 22/11/1975 25/12/2000       422
```